# Why is snap packages shown in lsblk output?

Tags: 16.04, snap

I recently installed a ubuntu-core snap package.
And this is the output of `lsblk`

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    1  14.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    1   1.9G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda2   8:2    1    13G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 149.1G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   100M  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0  59.9G  0 part 
└─sdb3   8:19   0    62G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
loop0    7:0    0  64.7M  0 loop /snap/ubuntu-core/109
```

Is this shown because each snap is sandboxed??

Answer (score 4):

Each snap (in 16, not in 15.04) is a squashfs file which, when installed, is mounted.

Comment: How do I find out if the snap if being currently used

Comment: the one you listed is `ubuntu-core`; if you don't have any others, then no, nothing is using it.

Answer (score 2):

lsblk shows volume information for all mounted file systems.  Because that one particular volume is still mounted it shows up in the lsblk output.

Comment: Why is it mounted?? Is it okay if i try to unmount it?

Comment: You could remove snapd which would remove ubuntu-core, but then you'd lose the ability to install applications which are packaged as snaps.